# Is it possible to change the buttons in inputManager of Unity3D's gamesettings?

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I am developing a 2D platform game, and is going to realize a function, let's use F to represent it, which could reverse player's control. For example, if I originally press A to make the character go left. After I use F, I press A to make the character go right.

The problem is that in my game,there will be two players using one keyboard to control 2 different characters. Both the characters use

```
float moveX = Input.GetAxis("HorizontalP" + player_number);
player_position = this.transform.position; 
this.transform.position = player_position;
```

which use buttons set in inputManager.
I can't use lots of **if else** to get the reverse control function. So I tried to seek for some ways to change the input button mapping by script while playing the game. However, I couldn't see any such answers to handle that. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: `I can't use lots of if else to get the reverse control function`  .. you Don't need to ... `if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){ multiplier *= -1; }` => tadaa every movement using that multiplier is now reversed ..

Comment: I won't give this as an answer as it would basically be a link-only answer, but I think you'd benefit from reading [the chapter about state](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html) in Robert Nystrom's "Game Programming Patterns" book. It addresses the curse of lots of `if else`. Good luck with the competition!